# Is it ok to use 14/2 wire out of a light in order to wire a receptacle into the ceiling?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I have a light in my workroom which I want to run some LED strip lights off of. I was going to use a simple light socket to outlet adapter and plug them in, but I just found out they need a ground plug. Is it ok (and up to code) to wire a receptacle in the ceiling using a new wire out of the light fixture using 14/2 wiring? I would assume this is running off of a 15 Amp breaker already, but I suppose I should check.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that.

However, one possible catch is **GFCI**.

Generally speaking, GFCI is now required in many areas, including unfinished basements, workrooms, etc. GFCI is, in most cases, **not** required for permanently installed lighting fixtures. In addition, GFCI, when used, has to be accessible - not in a receptacle in the ceiling.

Assuming you need GFCI for a receptacle in this room (which is likely but not an absolute), and assuming the circuit is not already GFCI-protected (which is likely the case - lighting circuits are not usually GFCI-protected), that leaves three options:

- Install GFCI protection at the breaker or someplace earlier in the circuit.
- Install a receptacle but within reach (i.e., on a wall in the first 6', rather than in the ceiling) and put GFCI there.
- Use hardwired (permanently installed) lighting instead of plug-in lighting.

Comment: I "May" be ok here. This room is drywalled, and will have flooring installed in it too. I will be doing a variety of different thing in this room and it is also the only room in the basement without a finished ceiling. I guess it depends on how you interpret the "Finished" word in the code.